# AWS SDK JS v3 Get presigned url react front end

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, sdk

Generate a presigned URL for PutObject

With Client and Command
ES6 Example:

```
   // ...
   import { S3Client, PutObjectCommand} from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
   // ...
   const command = new PutObjectCommand(putObjectParams);
   const url = await getSignedUrl(client, command, { expiresIn: 3600 });
```

ref: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/generate-presigned-url-modular-aws-sdk-javascript/

can anyone explain what putObjectParams and client should be ?
im trying to get presigned url aws sdk js v3. for uploading images from browser.
can't find any examples.

Answer (score 0):

refer -https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_s3_request_presigner.html

```
import { getSignedUrl } from "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner";
import { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
const client = new S3Client(clientParams);
const command = new GetObjectCommand(getObjectParams);
const url = await getSignedUrl(client, command, { expiresIn: 3600 });
```

bellow is how I have used

```
import { getSignedUrl } from "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner";
import { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-s3";
const client = new S3Client({ 
  region: config.region,
  credentials: { 
    accessKeyId: config.accessKeyId,  
    secretAccessKey: config.secretAccessKey,
  },
});
const command = new GetObjectCommand({
    Bucket: 'bucket-name',
    Key:'/path/img.jpg',
    ACL:'public-read',
  });
const url = await getSignedUrl(client, command, { expiresIn: 3600 });
```

use typescript so all the possible values of S3Client and GetObjectCommand can be displayed by IntelliSense

Comment: I was considering to use the javascript SDK, but I believe this is unsafe as you have to have your AWS credentials in the frontend code, which can then be picked up by anyone. I thought maybe whitelisting the app server, but that wouldn't matter as the request would come from the client.

Comment: @PaulMoers you are right, I run this code on AWS SAM